# jQuery Cycle2 auto trigger next slide when video or image has ended

Tags: jquery

I am using the Cycle2 plugin in jQuery to make a videos and images slideshow.
The sample in the offcial site put two button to trigger next or previous slide.
But I have to auto jump to next slide(maybe image or video) when the video finished playing.
And auto jump to next slide(maybe image or video) when the image reach to the timeout setting.
Is it possible that images have themselves timeout setting and video will play to the end.
And then auto jump to next slide.

code in the official site

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow"
data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
data-cycle-timeout=0
data-cycle-prev=#prev
data-cycle-next=#next
data-cycle-auto-height="640:360"
data-cycle-slides=">a"
data-cycle-youtube=true
data-cycle-youtube-autostart=true
>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/f7AU2Ozu8eo?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0">Paul Irish</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/seX7jYI96GE?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0">Alex Russel</a>
```

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/video.php

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check the `transition plugins` section: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/